# How to insert data into a SQL CE database after a bulk insert?

Tags: sql-server-ce, bulkinsert

I'm using ErikEJ's [SQL CE Bulk Copy](http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/) library to copy the contents of one database into another. The problem is, after the bulk copy is complete, `AUTOINC_NEXT` in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is still just equal to 1 for all primary key columns, causing a duplicate key exception when I try to insert a new row somewhere. Is there a way to make SQL CE Bulk Copy automatically update `AUTOINC_NEXT` to an appropriate value? Or alternatively, is there some utility I can use to manually edit it? (I've tried [CompactView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/), but it just gives the error "Data cannot be updated in a system table or a schema information view.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have found a bug! I will look into it. https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/workitem/25951

Fix is:

```
ALTER TABLE [MYtable] ALTER COLUMN [Id] IDENTITY (1001,1);
```

Comment: @tnorden The fix is now checked into source. Would be very gratful if you could try it out!

Comment: I tried it, but got this exception when I called `SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer`:

Comment: System.DllNotFoundException was caught
  HResult=-2146233052
  Message=Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
  Source=System.Data.SqlServerCe
  TypeName=""
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.BeginTransaction()
       at ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer(ISqlCeBulkCopyInsertAdapter adapter)
       at ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table, DataRowState rowState)

Comment: (I was using ErikEJ.SqlCe40.dll, so I don't know why it was asking for a SQL CE 3.5 DLL)

Comment: You probably compiled with the wrong reference... I will upload an updated .zip file soon

Comment: Maybe we could continue the support discussion here https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/workitem/25951 ?